# Интеграция C# и JavaScript запрос к серверу

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Вот это мой код:

```
function commandResult() {
    (function(callback) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", 'http://127.0.0.1:11005/scan/', true);
        //здесь получаю количество для сканирования
        xhttp.send("<%=ScanPageCount()%>");
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                callback(xhttp.responseText);
        };
    })(function(respMessage) {
        console.log(respMessage);
        document.getElementById('myPXText').value = respMessage;
        ///здесь получаю и передаю в C# функцию 
        ///сканированный текст
        var tmp = '<%=ImageScan(myPXText.Text)%>';
    })
}
```

Этот код используется в системе `AcumaticaERP`.
В системе `AcumaticaERP` у меня две функции `ScanPageCount()` и `ImageScan()`.

```
 public string ScanPageCount()
    {
         //передает количество для сканирования 
        return  this.MyPanel.Current.PageCount.ToString();
    }
    public void ImageScan(string[] jstr)
    {
        //получает ответ сервера то есть сканированные картинки и  
         //делает какую-то работу
    }
```

Но при этом сканирование не работает. Как правильно реализовать это в системе `AcumaticaERP`?

Comment: У Вас есть инпуты на форме или label у которого есть id? JS не понимает что такое '<' в аргументах. Вы должны передать какие-то данные уже в сериализированом виде и если Вы уже используете jQuery - то отправляйте данные через `$.ajax` или `$.post` в Вашем случае

Comment: Да label есть,но как понять  " JS не понимает что такое '<' в аргументах"

Comment: JS думает что '>' - это оператор и пытается что-то сделать. А ему нужны данные - строковые.

Comment: тогда почему это работает правильно alert("<%=ScanPageCount()%>")

Comment: Возьмите `label ID` и достаньте значение количества страниц через `jQuery` : `$('label#label_id_here').val()`

Comment: Потому, что Вы взяли значение в кавычках, а не "голым"

Comment: @RomanKozin кажется, вы не понимаете основную проблему. `<%= ... %>` - это в WebForms подстановка на стороне сервера. Каким образом она дошла до клиента в неизменном виде - не хочу даже гадать...

Comment: не стоит удалять вопрос, и сразу задавать точно такой же.

Comment: понятно но прежный был изменённый вариант поэтому удалил

Comment: а я вижу, что абсолютно одинаковый текст у удаленной версии и у этого вопроса.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin  лучше бы в метках отмечали систему `acumatica` что бы получить ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас есть данные на форме с количеством страниц, то можно сделать отправку следующим образом:

```
    function scan() {
        $.post('://localhost:11005/scan', 'pages=' + parseInt($('label#id').text()), function (response) {
            $('label#CstLabel').text(response);
        });
    // Или
       $.post('://localhost:11005/scan', 'pages=<%=ScanPageCount()%>', function (response){
        $('label#CstLabel').text(response);
       });
    }
```

Убедитесь, что данные приняты в формате `application/json`.

По Вашей просьбе пишу Ваш обновленный вариант
Версию `jQuery` возьмите Выше. Хотя бы 1.7.1.

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#StartButton').on('click', function () {
            $.post('http://127.0.0.1:11005/scan/', "<%=ScanPageCount()%>", function (response, xhr, status) {
                if (status.status == 200) {
                    $('#CstLabel')
                            .text(response)
                            .val(response);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: И как это использовать в моём примере? если не трудно напишите изменённый вариант

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, минутку

Comment: заранее спасибо

Comment: А как быть с этой строкой?   <%=ImageScan(CstLabel.Text)%>

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, а что она должна делать?

Comment: принять ответ из сервера о обработать `ImageScan` это C#  функция  которое  принимает массив стрингов

Comment: @VardanVardanyan тогда впишите её после обработки ответа от сервера при коде `200 (ОК)`. Для начала хотя бы тот код протестируйте

Comment: снова **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Comment: @VardanVardanyan проследите за тем, на какой строке оно отображает ошибку

Comment: ошибка вот на этом строке `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: А где Вы прописываете подключения к скриптам?

Comment: вообще то этот код должен работать в системе `Acumatica ERP`